# Html not rendering in mac safari

Tags: javascript, html, replace, safari

I have .net core web site which works on windows and all browsers on mac except safari

Entire portions of html are missing in DOM instead I see $< symbols.

Also note that on safari website works for all most all pages except few pages.

Also , there are no errors in console except for error where I am trying access DOM nodes which are missing.

While looking in resources tab, everything seems to be there.

But missing in elements tab.

It should be rendered according to the resources tab html.

Disabling java script seems to render page correct.

But this not required in any other browser.

Even Internet Explorer is loading website correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior doesn't occur in Firefox or Chrome.

A new feature has been accepted for inclusion in the next version of the ECMAScript spec called 'Regex Named Capture Groups' which, as the name suggests, allows you to assign a name to a capture group in a regular expression. One of the things added by this feature is a new addition to the replacement string syntax which allows you to interpolate the value of a named capture group.

This syntax takes the form $ - note the $< at the beginning!

According to the latest iteration of the spec, if you haven't closed a $< with a corresponding >, it should be ignored and just treated as part of the text.

This broke some of libraries, I am using in my web app.

Namely JQuery.Steps